# Passing string as argument

Tags: c++

//EDITED:
follow up question:

But making the function as `isUnique(const char *s)` 
and then calling function as `isUnique(str.c_str())`  does not allow me to modify my string `str` in the function
//

I am having problem with passing a string:

```
bool isUnique(char *s)
{
    int arr[256] = {0};
    while(*s)
    {
        arr[*s]++;
        if(arr[*s]>1)
        {
            cout<<"not unique";
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    string str = "abcda";
    cout<<"1: True : unique, 2: False: Not Unique"<<endl<<isUnique(str);
}
```

> ERROR:cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'bool isUnique(char*)'

Comment: A side-note: You do not actually iterate over `s`, so the loop will never end. Add `s++` at the end of the loop.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in general? i think you've edited the initial question so a newcomer doesn't know the initial question?

Answer (score 10):

Pass the argument as:

```
isUnique(str.c_str());
```

And make the parameter type of the function as`const char*`:

```
bool isUnique(const char *s)
```

Because `std::string::c_str()` returns `const char*`.

Or even better, make the parameter `const string&`:

```
bool isUnique(const std::string & s);
```

And pass as you do : `isUnique(str)`. Inside the function you can use `s[i]` to access the characters in the string, where  `0 <= i < s.size()`.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
isUnique(str.c_str())
```

and make sure `isUnique` takes a `char const *` argument.

Comment: But if I pass like this: isUnique("abcdefghijkl"), it works and not when I pass it like this

str = "abcdefghi"; isunique(str);

Comment: @Roger: that's because `"abcdefghijkl"` is a `char[]` and not an `std::string`.

Comment: right! Thanks! and just one more, when you pass a string in C++, you essentially pass the reference right?

Comment: @Roger: when you pass a `char *`, you obviously pass a pointer. When you pass an `std::string`, you pass by value.

Comment: so that was why I was getting error
I was passing by value and not the address

Comment: what if my function is 
isUnique(char *s) 
that is,I dont want to have a const char *s in the function parameter.
I want to change the String in the function

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing a string. You are passing a `char *` and trying to create one from a `string`. Of course the conversion from `string` to `char *` is not automatic - they are two very different things.

I suggest that you write this function:

```
bool isUnique(const std::string& s)
```

Comment: But making the function as isUnique(const char *s) and then calling function as isUnique(str.c_str()) does not allow me to modify my string str in the function

Comment: @Roger: You don't modify a const std::string& s argument, either. If you need to modify the value of this parameter you can always make a copy: "string t = s;"

Comment: I dont want to use additional buffer

Comment: @Roger It's ok, don't use it, if you don't want. I gave you a solution to your compilation error, it is up to you to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Either change function to accept

`bool isUnique(const string& s)`

and pass the string as a const reference

or do as the two other fine people suggested.

This being C++ it would be preferable to pass a `const std::string&` unless of course you have to be compatible with some C code or just have a requirement of using C-strings.